# Invalid use of Null Access VBA even when IIF condition states not to check

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a date query so that null is returned if there is no date and only date value from date/time is pulled if there is date and time value

```
IIf(Nz(rst("DateAssigned"), "") = "", "NULL", "'" & DateValue(rst("DateAssigned")) & "'")
```

Now, I get the error:

> Run time error: '94' Invalid use of Null

When the `rst("DateAssigned")` value is null. I know this is coming from the `DateValue` function. Why is it trying to parse the `DateValue` when the value is null?

Does vba parse everything in the entire statement without checking the `IIF` condition? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Iif will evaluate both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your questions

> Why is it trying to parse the DateValue when the value is null?

and

> Does vba parse everything in the entire statement without checking the IIF condition? Or did I make a mistake?

is:

Because `DateValue` is used as an argument for a parameter of the `Iif` procedure.

In general:

A procedure can only be executed when all its parameters are known. Therefore, procedures that are given as arguments are executed first.

Comment: Isn't it really inefficient though? If the `IIF` condition is true then parse the middle one, else parse the right one. Why parse all 3 arguments when you can only parse two? The first Boolean condition in `IIF` is only going to return either `true` or `false`

Comment: I agree with you, but unfortunately it is what it is. ;-) You could use an 'If Then Else` construct, but then you can't use it in an expression or query unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right: VBA parses the entire IIF statement first before run it. Try this in immediate window:

```vb
?IIf(1 = 1, "NULL",  DateValue(NULL))
```

You will get the same error.

I suggest you use the regular IF statment (if you do not want to use it inside of a query)

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure, that no invalid values are passed to *DateValue*:

```
IIf(IsNull(rst("DateAssigned"), "Null", "'" & DateValue(Nz(rst("DateAssigned"), Date()) & "'")
```

But is would be more straight forward to use *Format*:

```
IIf(IsNull(rst("DateAssigned")), "NULL", Format(rst("DateAssigned"), "Short Date"))
```